# Difference between WAN IP & LAN IP

Tags: networking, wan

We have taken an Internet leased line connection. The ISP has given the below info.

```
Static WAN IP : XXX.227.XX.32/30 (Gateway XX.227.XX.34)

Static LAN IP : XX.124.XX.192/29
```

Can someone explain the difference to me?.

We have configured the WAN IP in our firewall and everything is working fine.

What does this *LAN IP* mean?  I know the LAN IP meaning (Local Area Network), but what does LAN IP mean *here*?

Is it a static IP.  If so, how to use this IP & how many LAN IPs are there?

Comment: Have you tried asking the ISP first? They're the ones who set up the network.

Comment: It looks like a routed block. You would set up the first block on the router's WAN, the second block could then be used in the LAN with a gateway on the first block. Not entirely sure - but the ISP I used to work for did things like that.

Comment: If you have a CIDR block, then it is a group of static IPs (look up CIDR on wikipedia for an explanation of what /29 translates out to). They are also public IPs and it is not required that you use them (you can NAT and just use the WAN IP if you desire. However, if you have servers, you can use the LAN IPs and use the gateway provided to route those through the WAN IP.

Comment: You haven't given any specific addresses, but in most cases the WAN IP is a public IP address that is routable through the Internet. The LAN IP refers to a private IP address, which anyone can manage the addresses however they want. In your case "anyone" would refer to your ISP. You can read about the differences of [public vs private IP](https://www.iplocation.net/public-vs-private-ip-address).

Comment: is `XXX.227.XX.32/30` the IP or the network address? I would concur with MaQleod's comment.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer: LAN IP is like an *internal* (local) IP address that's just for **your** home, work, school PC's & devices in your **local** network. The LAN IP won't work outside of the local network (LAN IP address for everything connects to a router on your LAN: modem, other computers, phones, printers and any other devices).

WAN IP is like your address for the web that your Internet Service Provider (ISP) gives you (gives your router and you).

- **LAN IP**: 192.168.1.1  -like an internal address only for your network, say at home or work). You can have different devices on your LAN that have addresses like 192.168.1.5  or 192.168.1.13
- **WAN IP**: 216.119.143.xx  -an address the world sees for you when you browse the web.
- **Gateway IP** is the WAN address dedicated to the modem (like 216.119.143.50).

> Note: A Virtual Private Network (VPN) puts you on its private network so no one sees your external IP that your ISP gave you, which means it's harder to track you. Make sense?

**Static LAN** means that instead of letting the router's DHCP assign IP address to a PC or device, you set an IP that is *static*, i.e. remains the same – even if you disconnect from the LAN. Your ISP doesn't give you a static IP for your LAN, only WAN (if you need that). People use a static LAN so they can remember their  Local IP address to make it easier for networking sharing, and for like shared printers or media players. You don't want DHCP to assign a new local IP address each time you connect or reconnect to your local router.

Comment: This answer is not correct, not in this context. For example: the ISP DOES give out a static LAN IP (as the OP states)! Note that the OP asks for a leased line (usually a dedicated, fixed-bandwidth data connection) and not the standard DSL end consumer internet connection!

Answer (score 0):

LAN IP address is the address given to your host within your local area network, while your WAN IP would be the address given to your routers interface that is connected to the internet, usually at your point of demarcation between you and your ISP.